# radio button auto check based on condition using jstl

Tags: jstl

i need to set the radio button as checked based on the value present in the request. below is the code i used in my JSP

```
<input type="radio" name="status" id="status" value="Active" checked="<c:if test="${posting.postingStatus eq 'Active'}">checked</c:if>">
                Active&nbsp; 
<input type="radio" name="status" id="status" value="Closed" checked="<c:if test="${posting.postingStatus eq 'Closed'}">checked</c:if>">
                Closed
```

I am getting the radiobutton along with the text 'checked/>Active' and another radio button with text 'checked/>Closed'

i tried using another set of code

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${posting.postingStatus eq 'Active'}">
    <input type="radio" name="status" id="status" value="Active" checked="checked"/>
    Active&nbsp; 
    <input type="radio" name="status" id="status" value="Closed"/>
    Closed
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    <input type="radio" name="status" id="status" value="Active" />
    Active&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="status" id="status" value="Closed" checked="checked"/>
    Closed
    </c:otherwise>
```

i am getting double times with improper result.

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this way:

```
    <input type="radio" name="status" id="status"
     value="Active" ${posting.postingStatus=='Active'?'checked':''}>
```

Comment: @Alex Although I dont understand why one cant go like: <c:if test="${posting.postingStatus == 'Active'}"><c:out value="checked"/></c:if> Your is nicer and works, but it bugs me that I cant understand why mine doesnt work. Any clue? Hope you understand what Im trying to do :)

Comment: @brat you can do it with c:if but inline condition is shorter and cleaner.